# std:unordered_map insertion <value, Struct>; Arithmatic exception den__ is zero

Tags: c++, struct, hashmap, gdb

I have a code where I am inserting a struct in a unordered_map.

```
INFO Info( v1, UINT_MAX, v3, v4, v5 );
hmap_.insert( std::pair< key,INFO >( v1, Info ) );
```

at the above line I put a break point using gdb and Print the value of all the variables: All are fine gets printed as expected.

```
(gdb) p Info
$4 = {v1_ = valid_value, v2 = valid_value, v3 = , v4 = valid_value, v4 = valid_value}
```

Now when I go into the insert function of hash map using

```
(gdb) s
```

I get

```
(gdb) s
std::pair<unsigned long, namespace::class::Info>::pair<unsigned long&, namespace::class::Info&, true> (this=0x7fffffffd7e0, __x=@0x7fffffffd768: 1100000000000549, __y=...) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:331
331     : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(std::forward<_U2>(__y)) { }
(gdb) n

Thread 1 "test_1" received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x000055555556b105 in std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing::operator() (this=0x555555e09ec0, __num=1100000000000549, __den=0) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:448
448     { return __num % __den; }
```

As it can be seen in the gdb: while hashing it makes the denominator, which it produces from the second variable whose value I have printed and its correct, Zero (__den =0 ) !

I have a struct Info in another file with a normal constructor:

```
struct INFO
            {    
                Info():
                    v1_( 0 ), v2_( UINT_MAX ), v_3( INVALID ),
                    v4_( 0 ), v5_( 0 )
                {}

                Info( value_type1 v1, const value_type2& v2,
                        value_type3 v3, value_type4 v4, value_type5 v5 ):
                    v1_( v1 ), v2_( v2 ),
                    v3_( side ), v4_( v4 ), v5_( v5 )
                {}

                value_type1 v1_ ;

                value_type2 v2_ ;

                value_type3 v3_ ;

                value_type4 v4_ ;

                value_type5 v5_ ;
            };
```

Why would while hashing the denomator which is I guess is getting created from the second value of the pair which is a valid value will become zero and generate an arithmetic exception.
Thanks

Comment: How did you defined 'value_type1', 'value_type2', ... How did you defined 'hmap_'?

Comment: all value_types are unsigned int except value_type3 which is an enum.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].